# ffmpeg hevc (x265) encoding

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, video-encoding, h.265

i'm trying to use h265 encoder in ffmpeg library but give me this error:

```
Cannot open libx265 encoder.
```

this is my code:

```
formatContext = avformat_alloc_context();
videoStream = avformat_new_stream(formatContext,0);
if(!videoStream ) {
    //error
    return;
}
av_init_packet(&packet);
codecContext=videoStream->codec;
codecContext->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
codecContext->width = width;
codecContext->height = height;
codecContext->time_base.den = fps;
codecContext->time_base.num = 1;
codecContext->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
codecContext->codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_HEVC;
AVDictionary *param = 0;
av_dict_set(&param, "x265-params", "qp=20", 0);
av_dict_set(&param, "preset", "ultrafast", 0);
av_dict_set(&param, "tune", "zero-latency", 0);
av_dict_set(&param, "qmin", "0", 0);
av_dict_set(&param, "qmax", "69", 0);
av_dict_set(&param, "qdiff", "4", 0);
codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codecContext->codec_id);
if (!codec) {
    //codec not found
    return;
}
int rt = avcodec_open2(codecContext, codec, &param); // <----- fails here
if (rt < 0) {
    // fails here!!
    return;
}
```

This code works for h264 encoder, anyone know why doesn't work with hevc?

Comment: Did you build libx265?

Comment: no i'm using ffmpeg from here: http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/
latest build

Comment: Did you register the codec with `avcodec_register`?

Comment: yes, sorry if i don't write it before, because i register all in other function called before the code i've posted:

av_register_all();
avcodec_register_all();

Comment: Did you download the shared build which contains avcodec-55.dll after 2/12?

Comment: tryed with ffmpeg-20140306-git-bba7b6f-win32-shared but does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set

```
codecContext->sample_aspect_ratio.num = 4;
codecContext->sample_aspect_ratio.den = 3;
```

HEVC encoder will work, but there is no video on the output.

Comment: true, with your settings i can initialize well the codec, but now i get "Access violation reading ...". I don't know if i'm passing wrong data, but if i switch to h264 all works well...

Comment: Did you download again ffmpeg from ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds ?

Comment: Or is your video aspect ratio is 4:3 or 16:9, if it is the second one you have to set : sample_aspect_ratio.num = 16; and sample_aspect_ratio.den = 9;

Comment: yes i've downloaded ffmpeg from zeranoe.com, my video is 4:3 (400:300)

Comment: You "Access violation .." Come from a another thing, perhaps you try to get the packet before it finish to be encoded.

Comment: i don't know, i pass data to a function "encode" and if it encodes data then return it and lenght=n, otherwise return data=0 and lenght=0, from the call stack it seems to have access violation inside avcodec-55.dll

Answer (score 1):

Hi, did you reach to open `libx265` encoder ?
I've had the same trouble and tried using `AV_CODEC_ID_H265` instead.
I've had the same trouble before with `libx264` but i resolved it, by setting :

```
av_dict_set(&param, "profile", "high", 0);
```

It seems that something was missing in the codec configuration.

Comment: in avcodec.h there is this #define AV_CODEC_ID_H265 AV_CODEC_ID_HEVC so can be used both, i've added your profile high before preset and tune but now i have:

Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'high'
Unable to parse option value "high"
Error setting option profile to value high.

Comment: Sorry we misunderstood, i think that profile parameters is only for libx264. And certainly, there miss something like this, in the configuration of the libx265

Comment: You are a life saver.